# Covariance between a binomial random variable and its size (number of trials) (found in the context of binomial thinning)

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, random-variable, covariance, derived-distributions

Assume we have a random variable $X$, and we construct another random variable $Y$ to be from a binomial distribution of size $X$ and success probability $\alpha$, i.e., $Y \sim Binom(X, \alpha)$. How can you derive the covariance of $X$ and $Y$?

In the literature I am looking into (see below), it has been stated that $Cov(X, \alpha \circ X) = \alpha \cdot Var(X)$. How can I prove that?

---

#### Background

I am studying discrete-variate time series models such as integer-valued autoregressive models (specifically, INAR(1)) ([Al-Osh & Alzaid, 1987](https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9892.1987.tb00438.x)). At the core of the model lies the binomial thinning operator " $\circ$ " (first introduced by [Steutel & van Harn, 1979](https://sci-hub.se/https://www.jstor.org/stable/2243313)) as defined below (rephrased from Weiß, 2018):

> If $X$ is a r.v. with range $\mathbb{N}_0$ and if $\alpha \in (0;1)$, for *counting series* $Z_i$ (with $P(Z_i=1) = \alpha$), the r.v. $\alpha \circ X := \sum_{i=1}^{X} Z_i$
> is said to arise from $X$ by *binomial thinning*.

It is easy to show that $(\alpha \circ X)|X \sim Binom(X, \alpha)$.

In the literature (e.g., [Al-Osh & Alzaid, 1987](https://sci-hub.se/https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9892.1987.tb00438.x); [McKenzie, 1985](https://sci-hub.se/10.1111/j.1752-1688.1985.tb05379.x); [McKenzie, 2003](https://sci-hub.se/10.1016/s0169-7161(03)21018-x)), the autocorrelation function of INAR(1) is asserted to be $\rho(k) = \alpha^k$ (for $k \geq 0$).

As far as I could get, this is first derived by Al-Osh and Alzaid (1987) and cited afterward. In doing so (p. 265, Eq. 3.3), they substitute $Cov(X, \alpha^k \circ X)$ with $\alpha^k \cdot Var(X)$, but I am failing to derive it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just addressing the narrow initial question, not the general context you cited below. The key is the Law of Total Expectation, often written as $E[X] = E[E[X|Y]]$.

A common form of covariance is: $\text{Cov}(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$.

By the Law of Total Expectation, $E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]] = E[\alpha X] = \alpha E[X]$, so the subtracted term is $\alpha E[X]^2$. Note, the "inner" expectation is over the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ (i.e., the thing we understand), while "outer" expectation is just over $X$ as usual.

With both $X$ and $Y$ involved,

$E[XY] = E[E[XY | X]] = E[X E[Y|X]] = \alpha E[X^2]$. The critical step is $E[E[XY | X]]$, where the "inner" expectation is again conditioned on a specific $X$, and the outer expectation is over the variable $X$.

Thus, in total, we have

$\text{Cov}(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = \alpha E[X^2] - \alpha E[X]^2 = \alpha \text{Var}[X]$.

Hope all the steps are clear. The tricky part of working with the Law of Total Expectations is keeping the conditioning straight, sometimes it's clarifying to write it out as integrals over the given distribution.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't follow how you get from E[E[XY|X]] to E[XE[Y|X]].

Comment: Ah, I think I got it: E[XY|X] = E[X|X]E[Y|X] + cov(X,Y|X), wherein E[X|X] = X and the conditional covariance becomes zero. Am I right in this reasoning?

Comment: The broader intuition is just that when we condition on X (within the expectation), X is a constant, thus it can be factored out of the expectation (as if it were any constant). In words, E[XY|X] is "the expectation of the term XY, given a fixed value of X". When you write out the conditional covariance, you are essentially doing the same thing, but I think imagining the underlying definition of E[XY|X] might be more intuitive in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, @Ziddletwix, this makes sense.